# How to add contains logic on azure search throught List<int>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-search-.net-sdk

```
   {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "id": "1",
            "FullName": "Adam",
            "UserName": "Adam1903",
            "IsVerified": true,
            "PartitionKey": "32fbq",
            "IsSearchableUser": true
        }
```

Thats is my document on azure search index... I have collection List followedUsers = new List(){1,3};... what I want to achieve in azure search is something like this...

```
Select * from User where Id is in(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all the search result into List<> and use the following code to filter by id in array list.

```
var s = new List<Search>();
var exceptions = new int[] {1,2,3};
var filtered = s.Where(x=> exceptions.Contains(x.id));
```

Update:

If you want to use [`SearchParameters.SearchFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters.searchfields?view=azure-dotnet) Property to query parameter pegs search to specific fields, you could use the following code to query specific Id field.

```
parameters = new SearchParameters()
{
    SearchFields = new[] { "id" }
};
results = indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>("1", parameters);
```

Comment: I dont think that it would be useful because I want something like this Filter = $"search.in(id,{string.Join(',', FollowedUsersIds)})",

Comment: i want to filter while searching and not after search results returned

Comment: But if you want use list<> with filter, you need to populate the filter value in it first.

Comment: Why do you not use `Filter = $"search.in`?

Comment: var searchParameters = new SearchParameters()
                        {
                            SearchFields = new List<string>() { "FullName", "UserName" },
                            Filter = $"search.in(id,{string.Join(',', FollowedUsersIds)})",
                            ScoringProfile = "SearchProfile"
                        };

Comment: Like this one??

Comment: So you want use SearchParameters with List<>, right?